# iframe tracking events using iframeTracker

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-analytics

I need to track onClick events inside iframe. I'm using iframeTracker plugin through Google tag. Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.iframe_wrap #FJbanner').iframeTracker({
        blurCallback: function(){
            dataLayer.push({
                'event':'event', 
                'eventCategory':'Ad', 
                'eventAction':'click', 
                'eventLabel':'FJbanner'
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

but it's not working somehow. My other analytics is working though (tracking events within my site)
**FJbanner** is iframe Id I need to track

I'm using Universal Analytics

Comment: is your jQuery selector absolutely correct?  I suspect you need to remove the .iframe_wrap from it and just use $('#FJbanner') as you don't need a class if you've got a unique ID on iFrame.

Comment: It's correct but currently I'm using this selector
`$('.iframe_wrap iframe').iframeTracker({`
to affect all iframe elements. No use

Comment: well as I understand jQuery selectors you're currently looking for 'all iframes with the class iframe_wrap'.  Have you given all your iframes that class?  Can I suggest you get rid of the class and just go for the DOM element iFrame such $('iframe').iframeTracker etc

Comment: You're right. I specified the class now but nothing changed. I think it would be simpler to understand if you look at the html - http://hlcss.ml/

Comment: how do i get an iframe to show on that page, i can see them in the HTML but can't show any to click on!

Comment: There is a small banner with target iframe at the very bottom of the page, the only one with class 'iframe_wrap'

Comment: Ok, i think you're getting all a bit mixed up.  If you want to fire a separate event for each iframe, place an ID on the iFrame and then just use a jquery ID selector $('#FJbanner'), if you want a set event for every iframe on the page, just use the iFrame selector $('iframe') - the rest of the code works just fine. use the console to test your selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. It's all about Google Tag settings. There is a trigger which fires when you send an event like this

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event':'GAevent', 
    'eventCategory':'Ad', 
    'eventAction':'click', 
    'eventLabel':'FJbanner'
});
```

trigger expression

```
Event contain GAevent
```

so my error was that I didn't set it up correctly. You should specify an event name in a trigger settings according to Event variable value, 'GAevent' in my case